# Motherboard resets every time after computer plug in, windows time set to latest when it had electricity

Tags: motherboard, bios

if I turn off the computer and unplug it from the electricity socket, after plug it  again the first thing I'll see something like:

> reset to factory settings
>
> F1 continue, F2 setup

(msi motherboard)
if I leave it unplugged for 2 days and turn it on after, in windows I'll get the time from the last time I turned it on (for about 30 seconds, until it adjusts)

this computer hasn't been used for a long time (years), after it was cleaned a bit with the vacuum

Comment: You probably need to replace the CMOS battery.

Comment: +1, CMOS battery is flat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is highly likely to be a discharged CMOS backup battery. In my experience, they tend to last around 3-5 years, although it depends on how ofter the machine is left powered off with the mains supply removed.

Pop the hood and find the CR2032 battery likely located somewhere near the bottom right-hand side of the motherboard. Remove the existing battery, and replace it with a new CR2032 3V battery ensuring the correct polarity.

If it has a soldered retaining mount like the one in the image below, then you might struggle to replace it.

[image]